Can these wires be cut/shortened?
I've got a light fitting with 3 hanging pendants. All the slack lead in coiled up in the ceiling rose, the connection we have is a ring main so very bulky and can't fit it all in the ceiling rose. Can these slack be cut off and re wired to give more space. I'll try to add pics

They should be able to be shorten, if you take pictures and label the wires so you make sure all go back the same.  Make sure not to cut too short so the wires need to be pulled hard to fit back in the connectors.

On the American side of the pond there would be a box in the ceiling that serves several purposes. It provides room for the connections. It contains arcs so fires don't get started. It provides structural support for the fixture. Is that not required where you are? If you do remove slack do it from the fixture wires, not those coming from the ceiling. The next time the fixture is replaced someone will be very unhappy if there is barely a crouton of wire left to work with.

Are you talking about taking up slack in the lamp cord, or in the ceiling wiring?

the wires were cut in the factory ... that answers the title question ... cutting is easy, you should really be asking how to connect the wires? ... please show a closeup of each of the connections ... also show how the wires are terminated in one of the three lamps
